# JAuthentication: :authenticate: Failed to load plugin: plgauthenticationcookie Invalid password

Tags: joomla-2.5, login

When trying to log in I am seeing the following error message:

> JAuthentication: :authenticate: Failed to load plugin: plgauthenticationcookie Invalid password

I am not able to log into the back end with any users. (Version Joomla 2.5)
Does anyone know where I should check to try to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Having done some research on the topic, I found this:

http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=624&t=659815

The solution provided by the author says to completely removed the **plugins** directory and replace it with a fresh copy from a new copy of Joomla, which you can download here

https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/releases/download/2.5.28/Joomla_2.5.28-Stable-Full_Package.zip

Hope this helps

Comment: Sir i try this .. it totally down my site ...

Comment: What do you mean by "**it totally down my site**"? Did you get a blank screen or error messages?

Comment: means no display on front end and back end as well...

Comment: Please open your **configuration.php** and set `$error_reporting` to `development`. Once done, report back any errors. Could you also let me know your exact Joomla version...not just "2.5", but the number after, for example "2.5.28"